# FireAuth phone verification not working after release

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I successfully used phone verification in debug mode through `FireAuth`.

However after I release this app, it stop working and throws below error message.

I add SHA:1 and SHA:256 keys of google console to firebase project.

What is the problem?

```
E/FirebearCryptoHelper: Exception encountered during crypto setup:
    Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
E/FirebearCryptoHelper: KeysetManager failed to initialize - unable to get Public key
E/RecaptchaActivity: Could not generate an encryption key for reCAPTCHA - cancelling flow.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 139
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 7928726295
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred. [ Failed to generate/retrieve public encryption key for reCAPTCHA flow. ]]- calling backend without app verification
I/ViewRootImpl@af348ef[RegisterActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
I/ViewRootImpl@af348ef[RegisterActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2280) new=(0,0,1080,2280) req=(1080,2280)0 dur=5 res=0x1 s={true 529370561488} ch=false fn=47
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 7928726304
W/gchunon_androi: Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/gchunon_androi: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
D/로그인 중복: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/gchunon_androi: Compiler allocated 4546KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
```

Comment: Did you release your app through the PlayStore? If so, then it must have been signed using [Google Play Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll) - grab your Play Signing key from the Play Publish console and add it to your Firebase project.

Comment: I have the same issue @Hyejung. After updating pub versions of firebase to latest, phone auth just hangs after calling verifyPhoneNumber on flutter.

I also added my dev sha1 (google play sha256 is also added and google play signs it automatically.) It's an issue for me on local/dev

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, seems it just took me to the browser to additional verification and I got the message "Unable to process request due to missing initial state."

Answer (score 0):

> As per my comments in the question's comments... This happened to me
> ON FLUTTER.

***This is the steps I took to resolve it. Try it but be patient while you're at it.***

> For the lazy and experienced: update your sha1 local key on your
> android app in Firebase console. Somehow that sucker reset.

***For those looking for a step by step guide (This is for flutter but regardless, you should be able to follow...kinda)***

1. Navigate to your `android/app` folder.
2. You should be seeing your `{whatever}.jks` file. If you don't... I'm sorry, not sure what to do.
3. Fetch your sha1 key by running `keytool -list -v -keystore upload-keystore.jks`
4. In the bunch of text the terminal will spit out, you'll see two keys. 1 will be SHA-1 and another SHA-256. Add both (if not yet) to your android app in firebase console.
5. In case you don't know where to add it: `Firebase console > select your project > project settings > scroll down > select your android app`, then add it under `SHA certificate fingerprints`.
6. After adding this, i'm not sure if it just takes some time but I was very impatient so I deleted the app, restarted my phone (lol, i know - overkill), re-ran the app and it worked.

Questions? Add it in the comments. I'm sure someone smart will answer you.